# Android - not accessible to landroid/app/instrumentation when extending application class

Tags: java, android

Im slowly trying to learn android but Ive run into a hang up that I can't quite figure out. I'm trying to work with some global variables. I have extended the Application class. I have added what I think is correct to the manifest (the name of the class is Fortune Crunch):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.marctremblay.test.fortunecrunch"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true"
        android:name=".FortuneCrunch">
        <activity
            android:name=".FortuneCrunchActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Then this is what I have in my FortuneCrunchActivity.java file:

```
package com.marctremblay.test.fortunecrunch;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Application;


import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

class FortuneCrunch extends Application{

FortuneCrunch()
{   
}


}


class FortuneCrunchActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    }

}
```

I have basically removed all my code to try and get this class working just to be sure the issue isnt with anything else. If I remove the android::name from my manifest I no longer get the error.

Here is the exact error

newInstance failed: Lcom/marctremblay/test/fortunecrunch/FortuneCrunch; not accessible to Landroid/app/Instrumentation;

I am stumped. I have this setup just as I have seen it in many examples. Ideas would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: I had similar issue and the problem was the Activity (class) being called was Package Private. Make sure the called class is accessor Public Class...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the `FortuneCrunch` class in its own file, `FortuneCrunch.java`, with this inside:

```
package com.marctremblay.test.fortunecrunch;
import android.app.Application;

public class FortuneCrunch extends Application {
  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    // Initialize your variables here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Also, make sure to explicitly make your class public by putting `public class XYZ` instead of just `class XYZ`.

Otherwise the class will be considered as `package`, which will result in the same error.

Comment: I encountered this problem while accepting automatic fixes from the Android Lint [Analyze - Inspect Code]. It changed my Application class from public to package access.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you get the below error, change the name of your global variable class (*FortuneCrunch*) and do the next steps carefully again.

> newInstance failed: ....